# Shell scripting using cURL on windows for beginner

Tags: php, windows, shell, curl

I have a long list of URLs saved in excel and have a shell script to use with cURL to retrieve all URLs with errors, redirects, and/or connection timeout. I have never used cURL or shell. I need to use it on windows. So far I only know how to get to " C:\MyCurl>curl ". I have my shell script saved in a notepad. Can someone please tell me in specific detail what to do, including what the script and URLs should be saved as? It would be very helpful as I do not want to have to do each one manually and could be useful for many times in the future. Thank very much for your time.

Comment: What's your shell script? You need to at least be able to run it and then ask questions if there's a problem.

Comment: runcurl()
{
curl --max-time 15 --connect-timeout 14 -Lkw "%{http_code} %{num_redirects} %{url_effective}" -x http:   :80 $ -o /dev/null
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough details to answer your question about using a curl with a shell script on your local machine. But you may want to consider avoiding a shell altogether. PHP has a robust curl library. If you add the function below to your PHP script and call it with the URL as the parameter like:

```
$result = file_get_contents_curl( $url );
```

you will have code that's far more portable and scalable.

```
function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  if ( curl_errno( $ch ) <> FALSE ) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;

}
```